# Using gulp and wiredep, socket.io is not added to index.html (even though it is in bower.json)

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, gulp, wiredep

I have angular, angular-ui-router and socket-io in my bower.json file.

When I run my gulp file (using wiredep), the two angular scripts are successfully added to my index.html file but the socket.io script is not - and I cannot figure out why. Thanks for any help

//command line

```
[21:56:06] Using gulpfile ~/dev/projects/ecommerceVidChat/gulpfile.js
[21:56:06] Starting 'default'...
[21:56:06] Starting 'bower-dependencies'...
[21:56:06] Finished 'bower-dependencies' after 6.24 ms
[21:56:06] Finished 'default' after 7.24 ms
```

//bower.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.13",
    "socket.io": "~1.3.4",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13"
  }
```

// gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.start('bower-dependencies')
});

gulp.task('bower-dependencies', function () {  
  gulp.src('./build/index.html') 
    .pipe(wiredep({
      directory: './build/bower_components',
      bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

//index.html

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

//package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.11"
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Socket.io* itself does not have *bower* support, remember that it's the server, and not the client.

You can serve the client script with the socket server by setting its `serveClient` option to `true`, and insert it in your `index` directly with:

```
 <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Or install the client script that is referenced in *bower* but with another name:

```
bower install -save socket.io-client
```

If this package does not have a `main` property, you will have to override it in your main `bower.json`:

```
"overrides": {
  "socket.io-client": {
    "main": "socket.io.js"
  }
}
```

This way, *wiredep* will automatically inject it in your `index.html`.

Comment: The value that worked for me for main was `dist/socket.io.js` when using yeoman and editing the bower.json file. Solution: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/666

Comment: `"main": "dist/socket.io.js"` will actually correctly work with wiredep

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes vendors exclude the optional [main](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#main) property in their `bower.json` file which, I believe, wiredep uses to compile the array of sourcefiles. Check the `bower.json` file *within* the `bower_components/socket.io/` folder to see if they've included that. If not, maybe you can do a pull request to socket.io or at least raise an issue?